# How can I easily make a chart showing what weeks a task was completed or not?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I'm trying to make a chart that shows who completed an inspection for each week. At my work, we run Sunday to Saturday and within that time period, we expect our guys to submit a truck inspection.

I want to put a report together using historical data that shows us who's inspecting their truck and who isn't. I've made a pivot table that does this but it's not very easy to read. I'd like to have a chart like the example pictured that I made by hand.

I have about 300 trucks I'm wanting to include on this report so doing it all by hand isn't going to work.

Thanks in advance!

Photos:

[image: Pivot Table]

[image: Chart made by hand]

[image: Data]

Comment: You should be able to get to your `chart made by hand` with a few changes to your `pivot table`. 1) move `signed at` from the row section to the column section. 2) go to: Design (last item menu item when you click on a cell in the pivot table) -> Layout -> Report Layout and select a) Show in Tabular form and b) Repeat all label items. 3) Remove certain subtotals/grandtotals.